# @Umbraco.TypedMedia(MyProperty) is null in Umbraco 7.6.1

Tags: umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 7.6.1 and I'm trying to get the url for a media image using the code below in razor.

```
@{
   var bannerMediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.Image); 
   var bannerUrl = bannerMediaItem.Url;
}
```

But bannerMediaItem is always null even though I know it exists. If I do this..

```
@Model.Content.Image
```

It returns the id of the image e.g. 1086

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us the property type in Umbraco of `Image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Umbraco v7.6 and above, there is now a new thing called UDI. Find out more about UDI here. https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/Udi

So instead of your media item having a numeric id, by default it will have an id like this: umb://media/39d3ac707d634953ab52642d5037855c

Here is how you get the media url when the id is one of the new type:

```
string imageUrl = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("headerImage").Url;
```

Comment: For more information about how to get media items and their urls, see my post here http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-a-media-item-in-umbraco/

Comment: Very interesting, this is good to know. However, I feel the Models Builder supersedes this approach (for those of us using it).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var propertyValue = content.GetPropertyValue<int>(propertyName); // this will give you the id of the media item
var media = helper.TypedMedia(propertyValue);

var url = media == null ? string.Empty : media.Url;
```

**propertyName** (string value) is the name of the property you have for your 
banner.

**content** is the IPublishedContent

**helper** is the UmbracoHelper that you will get from Umbraco.Web

Thanks

Comment: On this line... `var propertyValue = content.GetPropertyValue<int>("image");` I get...  'umbraco.content' does not contain a definition for 'GetPropertyValue'

Comment: This answer is good but I feel like it would be better if it fit the question better (like using `"image`" rather than writing `propertyName`).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I was nearly right and with help from @Harsheet this worked...

```
@{
   var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("image"));
   var thumbUrl = media.Url;
}
```

Comment: I am glad..it worked! So you can mark this as your solution as well.. And thanks for the vote up

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageTitleBackground = (Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("pageTitleBackground")) !=null ? Umbraco.TypedMedia((Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("pageTitleBackground"))).Url : String.Empty;



style="background-image: url('@pageTitleBackground');
```