# Can't get media image URL from Umbraco after upgrade

Tags: umbraco, upgrade, media

I have recently upgraded to 7.6.3 and I am having an issue retrieving media image URLs in my views. For testing purpposes, I added a new [MediaPicker2](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/Media-Picker2) property for one of the nodes, set up a value for it and tried to get its value in my razor view:

```
var icon2 = Model.Content.GetProperty("icon2");
```

The object then looks like this:
[image]

Executing `Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("icon2")` throws the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Umbraco.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Exception while creating a value.
>
> InnerException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

`Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("icon2")` throws the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In umbracoSettings.config is EnablePropertyValueConverters set to false or true?

Comment: It's set to true.

Comment: What version of Umbraco did you upgrade from?

Comment: I think you have some dll maybe from the PropertyValueConverter  plugin or  from a botched upgrade

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969818/2963111), what you're doing is correct. However, I'm not sure why it's not working.

However, I have answered a similar question to this before, and [I found a roundabout way of getting the node for a Udi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308918/2963111):

You can get an IPublishedContent from your image string using this code:

```
// Your string.
var imageString = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("icon2");

// Get the guid from this string.
var imageGuidUdi = GuidUdi.Parse(imageString);

// Get the ID of the node!
var imageNodeId = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.EntityService.GetIdForKey(guidUdi.Guid, (UmbracoObjectTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(UmbracoObjectTypes), guidUdi.EntityType, true));

// Finally, get the node.
var imageNode = Umbraco.TypedMedia(imageNodeId.Result);
```